# Using docker-compose Mysql + App

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I am trying to link two containers using docker.

MySQL Dockerfile:

```
...
EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["/usr/sbin/mysqld"]
```

App Dockerfile:

```
...
ADD . /services
CMD ["python", "-u", "services/run_tests.py"]
```

In the run_tests.py i used

```
self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql", user="XYZ", passwd="XYZ", db="TEST_DB")
```

In my docker-compose.yml:

```
app:
   build: .
   links:
      - mysql
mysql:
   image: XYZ/KJM
```

When i run `docker-compose up` i could not connect to mysql container.

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'rds'
>   (111)")

EDIT:
I dont know if i need to wait little to start the app docker. I imagine that the MySQL isnt up wheh the app try to connect.

Comment: i guess the host for mysql is 'mysql' instead of 'rds', no?

Comment: You are right. It was my mistake. But it is not the core problem.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and is yet to be addresses. Check out this link
[Docker services need to wait](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/374)

You are absolutely right that the MySql service is not yet up while your App container comes up very quickly and hence when it tries to connect to MySql, the connection is refused. On the application side what you can do is that you could write some retry logic. Something on these lines

```
while(numberOfRetries > 0) {

try {

  // Try to connect to MySql
} catch(Exception e) {

     numberOfRetries--;

     if(numberOfRetries == 0)
       // log the exception 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since Docker 1.13, this is now a solved problem. You can now use the [`HEALTHCHECK`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) directive in your MySQL Dockerfile:

1. Create a health check script that will `exit 1` when success: `select 1+1 from <table>` or something. Call this `health.sh`.
2. In your Dockerfile, copy `health.sh` to the container.
3. Use the `HEALTHCHECK CMD` to run the `health.sh` script.
4. In your compose file, modify your `app` definition:

   ```
   version: 2.1

   app:
     build: .
     links:
       - mysql
     depends_on:
       mysql:
         condition: service_healthy
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right that you need to wait. You can attempt the connection in a loop, and retry a few times with a short sleep between each attempt.

Comment: See my answer below